# Should Vi.SE be self-contained (as much as that is possible)?

Tags: discussion

This is probably something a lot of you have already thought about, but it doesn't seem to have been addressed here on meta (or I didn't manage to find the post).

A lot of topics, problems and solutions about vi/vim already exist scattered around the various sites of the stackexchange network, mostly on [stackoverflow], [superuser], [unix.se].

What are the policies on asking questions which already have answers on other SE sites? Would it be ok to answer such a question linking to the various related questions on the other sites and summing up the conclusions they reached?

---

Here is a practical example of what I mean: I was wondering today why backspace in insert mode does not delete the previous character as usual. This (very common I imagine) problem does not seem to have been addressed here on Vi.SE, but a little research led to

- [Backspace key not working in Vim/vi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11560201/4063051) on SO
- [vim not allowing backspace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10727392/4063051) on SO
- [Vim backspace key only works on new text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5019315/4063051) on SO
- [Backspacing with vim](https://superuser.com/q/396695/376608) on SU
- [Backspace key not working in vim](https://superuser.com/q/202848/376608) on SU

Also I won't mention a few posts on Unix.SE on related problems more terminal-oriented, and of course external resources like [vim.wikia.com](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Backspace_and_delete_problems), and so on and so forth. I think you got the point.

So clearly questions like these have already easily retrieved solutions scattered around. Would nonetheless be useful to address them on *this* site?
This *could* make sense to me as a way to better organize information that while already existing is scattered to the four winds, making Vi.SE a central hub for information about a specialized topic.
What do *you* think?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do we do with questions that are already answered somewhere else on SE?](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/questions/45/what-do-we-do-with-questions-that-are-already-answered-somewhere-else-on-se); another question about this: [Should we encourage asking questions that are already on another SE site?](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/questions/173/should-we-encourage-asking-questions-that-are-already-on-another-se-site)

Comment: To specifically answer the "backspace question": I think a better, more comprehensive answer can be given to this questions you linked to have. I would for example explain what these options do (aside from the `eol` value, this is not clear to me from just reading the help).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker dang! I knew it, but I swear I looked for it :). So the answer is: link them all and possibly write a better answer, right? Should I delete this question or do I leave it in the spirit of *redundancy (sometimes) helps searchability*?

Comment: I would personally not link any of these question. The answers on all of them are 'sufficient', but lack any additional detail or insight. What would linking to them provide? Anyone clicking on those links hoping to get more information would be wasting his or her time. If your answer lacks *less* detail than what these answers have, you should probably not post your answer at all.

Comment: You could delete this question, or leave it as it is. Your choice :-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I see your point. I'll ask the question, and then maybe the opposite could be done: link the yet-to-be answer in the other lower-quality questions around the network. I think this kind of linking would be useful, mostly because someone searching for such a solution would most probably first find SO or SU, not even knowing of the existence of this site.

Comment: Related: [Building a foundation for vi/vim knowledge](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/1201/88)

Comment: Related: [What is on topic here that cannot be asked on SO?](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1238/what-is-on-topic-here-that-cannot-be-asked-on-so)